# Issues with metadata converting mp3->ogg

Tags: mp3, ogg-vorbis

I'm trying to convert mp3 files to ogg, but I found a problem: most or all of the metadata is disappearing after the conversion. Is there a way to keep it?

Comment: Alexander - its a good question - upvote from me.  However, as I'm sure you are aware - converting from one lossy format such as mp3 to another lossy format such as ogg will lose you noticable audio quality.  If you can, re-rip your collection straight into ogg format.

Comment: Can you include information about how you're doing the conversion?

Comment: Have you tried using [soundconverter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/soundconverter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The userfriendly program *soundconverter* (Gnome Sound Converter) retains at least artist, title, album, comment and year(*) when converting to ogg.

The command line program *sox* retains at least artist, title, album and year(*), but apparently not comment.

```
sox xxx.mp3 xxx.ogg
```

(*) some programs may disagree if year is release time tag or recording time tag.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
id3cp -1 file.mp3 file.ogg
```

This should copy tags from mp3 file to the ogg one.

Comment: [user1671913](http://askubuntu.com/users/124107/user1671913) said about this method: "it'll write those tags as an id3 attachment, which most tools appear either ignore or mark as corrupt."